# Get Calendar Event Id from Meeting Request Mailbox Item

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, microdata

IS there a way to get the calendar event from a meeting request mailbox. I am using office.js and i cannot see any field that indicates the id of the event. As it appears, even when the meeting is updated and a new request email is sent, all the meeting requests in a single conversation are linked to the same calendar event object. Is there a unique identifier I can access from the Meeting Room Request mailbox item that I can use to query the calendar event.

Currently the way i do this is by checking that the created date of the calendar event is greater than or equal to the created date of the meeting request item or less than Meeting_Request CreatedDate

`MeetingRequestCreatedDate <=  CalendarEventCreatedDate  <= MeetingRequestCreatedDate + (someOffset)`

AND

`MeetingRequestCreatedDate <=  CalendarEventModifiedDate  <= MeetingRequestCreatedDate + (someOffset)`

The Offset i find necessary because sometimes the dates are not exactly in sync. The actual code is like this:

```
 //It might take a while for the modified date to update on the calendar event
        //therefore the margin of error is set to 2seconds
        const append = `/me/calendar/events?$select=LastModifiedDateTime,CreatedDateTime,Locations,Location,Organizer&
            $filter=(CreatedDateTime gt ${toUTCTimeZone(item.dateTimeCreated)} and CreatedDateTime lt ${toUTCTimeZone(item.dateTimeCreated, 2)}) or
            (LastModifiedDateTime gt ${toUTCTimeZone(item.dateTimeCreated)} and LastModifiedDateTime lt ${toUTCTimeZone(item.dateTimeCreated, 2)})
            `;

        const restUrl = `${Office.context.mailbox.restUrl}/v2.0${append}`;
```

Then finally I check to see if the orgernizer of the `CalendarEvent == MeetingRequestSender`

`result.Organizer.EmailAddress.Address == Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress`

I have two questions:

1. How do I avoid doing this (hack) of a query to get calendar events. A unique id of some sort will be better.
2. If not possible then how do I include the final step in the odata query. Adding the third condition that checks that the organizer is equal to the sender in the single odata query